# How to redirect user to specific page in certain condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC 5 and this is an intranet which users are authenticated using Active Directory.

I want to redirect the user to specific view if it is not part of specific Active Directory Groups. I can add below code in all controllers and actions

```
// AppUser.HasAccess() checked if user is part of specific Active Directory Group and returns bool
if(!AppUser.HasAccess())
{
    return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied");
}
```

But, I want to do that only in one or two place instead of spreading that piece of code every where.

I tried to change the _Layout.cshtml to do something like this but I got error which says I cannot skip calling @RenderBody()

```
<div class="container body-content">
    @if(AppUser.HasAccess())
    {
        @RenderBody()
    }
    else
    {
        @RenderPage("AccessDenied.cshtml") 
    }
</div>
```

I also tried hacking RouteConfig but in that stage the `HttpContext.Current.User` is null

Please let me know what is the simple way to doing this without having to implement custom Authorization attributes.

Comment: have you considered making an action filter?

Comment: No. If you think the easiest way is using action filter I'll try it

Comment: Well it's a good way to make code which is re-usable and can be applied to as many actions / controllers as you need, and can prevent an action from running if the criteria are not met. So yes, I'd say it was one of the better ways to implement this kind of requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an [ActionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) and check user access in the `OnActionExecuting` method which fires before action is executed.

I am not sure how you have implemented your `AppUser` class and how you will access it, but within an `ActionFilter` you can access `HttpContext` as shown below:

```
public class ValidateAccessFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var user = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
        // verify user permission
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // do something after the action executes
    }
}
```

If you want the above filter to execute on every request then you can register it globally as shown below:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        // global filters
        filters.Add(new ValidateAccessFilter());
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can register it on a specific `Controller` or a specific `Action` method.